# Spark job deployment failure to cloudera

Tags: apache-spark, guice, cloudera, spark-streaming, cloudera-cdh

I am using guice architecture upon developing my spark strreaming program. It can run in my eclipse without any error. However, after compiling and deployed with spark-submit command, it returns an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
```

After googling through, I noticed that this error only appears if we are using guice 3.0. But I am using guice 4.0. My spark version is 1.5.2, and my cloudera version is 5.3.2. Is there any work around on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, `Spark v1.5.2` depends on `com.google.inject:guice:3.0`.

So I suspect that what is happening is that that your project is pulling both:

- `Guice 4.0` (as a direct dependency stated in your dependencies file like `pom.xml` or `build.sbt`); and
- `Guice 3.0` (a transitive dependency pulled by `Spark v1.5.2`)

Basically your classpath ends up being a mess, and depending on the way classes are loaded by the classloader at runtime you will (or will not) experience such kind of errors.

You will have to use the already `provided` version of Guice (pulled by Spark) or start juggling with classloaders.

---

UPDATE:

Indeed the `org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.5.2` pulls `com.google.inject:guice:3.0` :

```
 +-org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.5.2 [S]
   + ...
...
   +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.2.0
   | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:2.2.0
   | | +-com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0
   | | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:2.2.0
   | | | +-com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0
   | | | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:2.2.0
   | | | | +-com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0
   | | | | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:2.2.0 (VIA PARENT org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn:2.2.0 and then VIA ITS PARENT org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-project:2.2.0)
   | | | | | +-com.google.inject:guice:3.0
...
```

The `spark-core` `pom.xml` is [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/1.5.2/spark-core_2.10-1.5.2.pom).

The `hadoop-yarn-common` `pom.xml` is [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.pom).

The `hadoop-yarn` `pom.xml` is [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-2.2.0.pom).

The `hadoop-project` `pom.xml` is [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-project/2.2.0/hadoop-project-2.2.0.pom).

Comment: Do you have any reference for the pom.xml ? I am suspecting that my classpath is in a mess.

Comment: Lol I cannot find any pom.xml that depends on guice itself, it is embarrassing. However if I create a fat jar using "spark-core" v1.5.2 as a dependency I can see that Guice 3.0 is included (why I got to the previous conclusion). I will get back to you once I have more information and I understand why it happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320695/guice-dependency-is-transitively-pulled-without-explicit-dependency

Comment: @DericDominic there you go :)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. :)

Comment: I think i am able to run it using guice 4.0 without using gwizard due to the version incompatibility from guava which is version 18.0 in gwizard but is version 11.0.2 in hadoop. The root cause of this error is due to the versioning of guava, i assumed is not backward compatible.

Comment: Glad to hear you identified the issue!