# Artifact is pulled without explicit dependency shown by sbt-dependency-graph

Tags: scala, sbt, guice

My almost-empty [SBT project here](https://github.com/mauriciojost/scala-sbt-dependencies) has only one dependency:

- `"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager" % "2.2.0"`

Checking [the pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.2.0.pom) of such artifact, it seems it does not depend on any `guice-servlet` artifact.

However when I run `sbt dependency-tree` I see something different, it does depend on a `guice-servlet` artifact:

```
user@laptop:~/workspace/pack$ sbt dependency-tree
[info] Loading project definition from /home/user/workspace/pack/project
[info] Set current project to pack (in build file:/home/user/workspace/pack/)
[info] eu.pepot.eu:pack_2.10:0.1 [S]
[info]   +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager:2.2.0
[info]     +-com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:3.0
[info]     | +-com.google.inject:guice:3.0
[info]     |   +-aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
[info]     |   +-javax.inject:javax.inject:1
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: From the POM you provided, it looks like hadoop-common is also a dependency, which has a bunch of other dependencies. Have you tried going down that rabbit hole? [hadoop-common](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0/hadoop-common-2.2.0.pom)

Comment: Like @Eric said it's a recursive transitive dependency until you get everything your top level dependency needs. That's what makes dependency resolution useful anyway - going as many levels as it has to.

Comment: @Aleksey what do you mean by "recursive"?

Comment: @mauriciojost I meant it works recursively. It gets dependencies for your dependency and checks if these dependencies themselves need other dependencies, and so on recursively until no more dependencies are required.

Comment: @Eric but `hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager` does not depend directly on `hadoop-common`, then why intermediate dependencies are not listed? Is it the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dependency comes from the parent pom, [hadoop-yarn](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-2.2.0.pom).

`hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager` use `hadoop-yarn-server` which use `hadoop-yarn`. This pom has a lot of dependencies, including Guice.

Comment: `hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager` does not depend directly on `hadoop-common`, then why intermediate dependencies are not listed? Is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: I didn't mention "hadoop-common". The dependencies come from the parent pom, this relation is not shown with your tool. Look at the pom.xml directly

Comment: The missing point was the parent dependency, not shown explicitly by the tool, thanks!